# csrftoken in django rest framework - sending through HTTPIE

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, httpie

I'm trying to login through the http form,  from DRF:

```
> https://my.site.io/api-auth/login/
```

Using httpie, i generate a session.json to get the CSRFToken:

```
$ http --session=why -h https://my.site.io/api-auth/login/
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: nginx/1.18.0
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=dT2UuBjp7Xei2iqzmD9A9lNNaTZO8ZHHPh098I8mV27v56E0jePTPgQ0KC3LDmpE; expires=Thu, 02 Dec 2021 15:32:49 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Vary: Cookie
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

I use the csrftoken from cookies and :

```
http --session=why -h POST https://my.site.io/api-auth/login/ username=user password=pass X-CSRFToken:dT2UuBjp7Xei2iqzmD9A9lNNaTZO8ZHHPh098I8mV27v56E0jePTPgQ0KC3LDmpE -p Hh
```

This is the out put  (With both request and response headers):

```
POST /api-auth/login/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, */*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 49
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: csrftoken=dT2UuBjp7Xei2iqzmD9A9lNNaTZO8ZHHPh098I8mV27v56E0jePTPgQ0KC3LDmpE
Host: my.site.io
User-Agent: HTTPie/2.3.0
csrfmiddlewaretoken: dT2UuBjp7Xei2iqzmD9A9lNNaTZO8ZHHPh098I8mV27v56E0jePTPgQ0KC3LDmpE

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 3366
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 03 Dec 2020 15:33:37 GMT
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: nginx/1.18.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

I tried to use **X-CSRFToken** instead of **csrfmiddlewaretoken**

I can perform the login through a browser, if a browser is working, i don't see as it can be a problem from the Django Rest Framework configuration. Maybe i'm doing something wrong with httpie

What can it be?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the last request example, I can see a `csrfmiddlewaretoken` header, but not the `X-CSRFToken` you specified in the command. Maybe you used a different command? In any case, this looks like the token is not valid.

Comment: @JakubRoztocil i tried both, to no avail. Thank you for your input .